# Better one global index or two more specified indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have Transaction table with the following fields

```
OID int
StartDate DateTime
Source int FK
TransactionType int
ArchivedDate DateTime (nullable)
```

There are two transaction types:

Regular (ArchivedDate is null and TransactionType=1) or Archived (ArchivedDate is not null and TransactionType=2).

In order to make our Regular transactions unique there is an filtered index on StartDate and Source filtered by TransactionType=1.

We would you like to also make our Archived transactions unique based on StartDate, Source and ArchivedDate.

Would I rather

- Replace the current index removing the filter and including
  StartDate, Source and ArchivedDate
- Or create a new filtered index on StartDate, Source, ArchivedDate
      filtered with TransactionType = 2

One last precision: The transaction are archived very occasionally so the record with TransactionType=2 represents less than 10% of the total records.

Comment: Is the relationship between `ArchivedDate` and `TransactionType` *enforced* within the database?

Comment: (Also, as with most question of this type, the answer is probably, try *both* with *your* data and *your* workloads and *measure* whether one works appreciably better than the other)

Comment: `ArchivedDate` and `TransactionType` are not enforced within the database.

Comment: If they're not enforced then you should realise that by changing the existing index you would potentially allow erroneous data to be inserted (since they could then insert multiple Regular transactions with identical `StartDate` and `Source` values but with random `ArchivedDate` values)

Answer (score 0):

I would do these as two separate filtered indexes/constraints.  Keeping a separate filtered index for your Regular transactions will continue to provide good performance as the relative volume of Archived transactions continues to increase.  The cost to maintain the additional Archived index should be very low as the archived status implies there is no activity to those records.